# ¿Por que no se están pasando los parámetros al modelo?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Estoy abriendo una nueva pestaña que contiene un **foreach** con los valores de una consulta sql una vez que hago click en un botón. La pestaña se abre correctamente, sin embargo, el valor de los parámetros no son pasados correctamente al modelo, provocando varios errores. ¿Por que no estoy logrando pasar los parámetros correctamente?

Error

```
Message: Missing argument 1 for M_Porcentaje::tabla_porcentaje(), 
called in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\C_Porcentaje.php 
on line 39 and defined

Filename: models/M_Porcentaje.php

Line Number: 34
```

Sale lo mismo para el otro parámetro

Controlador

```
 function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('M_Login');
    $this->load->model('M_Porcentaje');

}

 public function tabla_porcentaje(){

        $fecha_ini = $this->input->post('fecha_ini');
        $fecha_ter = $this->input->post('fecha_ter');

        $this->M_Porcentaje->tabla_porcentaje($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter);

        $data['consulta'] = $this->M_Porcentaje->tabla_porcentaje();
        $this->load->view('usuarios/test.php',$data);



 }
```

Modelo

```
public function tabla_porcentaje ($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter){

$start ="$fecha_ini 08:30:00 ";
$end = "$fecha_ter 22:30:00 ";

$this->db->select('motivos_citas.descripcion_mot,COUNT(*) AS cantidad_motivos, (SELECT COUNT(motivos_citas.descripcion_mot)* 100 / COUNT(citas.id_ci) FROM citas AS citas WHERE citas.fecha_ini BETWEEN "$start" AND "$end" ) AS porcentaje');
$this->db->from('citas');
$this->db->join('motivos_citas','citas.id_mot=motivos_citas.id_mot');
$this->db->where('citas.fecha_ini BETWEEN "$start" AND "$end" ');
$this->db->group_by('motivos_citas.descripcion_mot');
$consulta = $this->db->get();

if($consulta->num_rows() > 0 ){

return $consulta->result();

  }
}
```

AJAX

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn_buscar").click(function(evento){


    var fecha_ini =  $("#fecha_ini").val();
    var fecha_ter =  $("#fecha_ter").val();

   $.ajax({

     url: "<?php echo base_url();?>C_Porcentaje/tabla_porcentaje/",
     type: 'post',
     data: { "fecha_ini": fecha_ini, "fecha_ter": fecha_ter },

     success: function(response){ 

        alert($("#fecha_ini").val());
        alert($("#fecha_ter").val());
        window.open('<?php echo base_url();?>C_Porcentaje/tabla_porcentaje/', '_blank');
     }

    });

   });

  });
</script>
```

Los alert me traen las fechas de manera correcta

test.php

```
 <html>

 <head>
 <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/logo-32.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
 <title>Porcentaje de Cias</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h2 style="text-align:center;">Porcentaje de Citas</h2>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>

 <div>
 <img src=".img/logo-aiep.png">
 <div>
 <br></br>
 <div style="top: -100px;">
 <table style="border:1px solid red;width:100%;">
<tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Motivo</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Cantidad</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Porcentaje</th>
</tr>
           <?php foreach($consulta as $row){?>

           <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row->descripcion_mot ;?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row->cantidad_motivos ;?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row->porcentaje ;?></td>


           </tr>

       <?php }?>
   </table>
   <div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Justo aquí: `$data['consulta'] = $this->M_Porcentaje->tabla_porcentaje();` estás llamando al tabla_porcentaje sin pasar argumentos.

Comment: Como deberia de corregirlo para que fuese de manera correcta? agregue esa linea para que se mostrara el foreach con los datos en la vista, es decir para pasar los datos a la vista del archivo test.php

Comment: Vaya por delante que no tengo mucha idea de codeigniter, pero supongo que pasándole las fechas como argumentos, debería valer: `$data['consulta'] = $this->M_Porcentaje->tabla_porcentaje($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter);`

Comment: Esto me arroja ahora solo un error, que es el siguiente Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: usuarios/test.php

Line Number: 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero quería agradecer a Sergio Cauich por responder y corregir los errores que tenia. Sin embargo aun con esto no mostraba un resultado. Luego de consultar a otros programadores me aconsejaron no usar AJAX y pasar los datos por GET. Lo que funciono satisfactoriamente, quedando de esta manera el resultado:

Javascript

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#btn_buscar').on('click', function(){

     var fecha_ini =  $("#fecha_ini").val();
     var fecha_ter =  $("#fecha_ter").val();

     window.open('<?php echo base_url();?>C_Porcentaje/tabla_porcentaje?fecha_ini=' + fecha_ini + '&fecha_ter=' + fecha_ter);

      });

     });

 </script>
```

Controller

```
   function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('M_Porcentaje');


   }

   public function tabla_porcentaje(){


   $fecha_ini = $this->input->get('fecha_ini');
   $fecha_ter = $this->input->get('fecha_ter');

   $data['consulta'] = $this->M_Porcentaje->tabla_porcentaje($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter);
   $this->load->view('usuarios/test.php',$data);

   }
```

Model

```
public function tabla_porcentaje ($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter){

$this->db->select("motivos_citas.descripcion_mot,COUNT(*) AS cantidad_motivos, (SELECT COUNT(motivos_citas.descripcion_mot)* 100 / COUNT(citas.id_ci) FROM citas AS citas WHERE date(citas.fecha_ini) BETWEEN date('$fecha_ini') AND date('$fecha_ter') ) AS porcentaje");
$this->db->from("citas");
$this->db->join("motivos_citas","citas.id_mot=motivos_citas.id_mot");
$this->db->where("date(citas.fecha_ini) BETWEEN date('$fecha_ini') AND date('$fecha_ter') ");
$this->db->group_by("motivos_citas.descripcion_mot");
$consulta = $this->db->get();

 return $consulta->result();

}
```

Resultado test.php

```
 <html>

 <head>
 <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/logo-32.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
 <title>Porcentaje de Cias</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h2 style="text-align:center;">Porcentaje de Citas</h2>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>

<div>
<label>Fecha de Inicio:<?php echo $_GET['fecha_ini']; ?></label>
</div>

<div>
<label>Fecha de termino: <?php echo $_GET['fecha_ter']; ?></label>
</div>

<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<div>
<img src=".img/logo-aiep.png">
<div>
<br></br>
<div style="top: -100px;">
<table style="border:1px solid red;width:100%;">
<tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Motivo</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Cantidad</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Porcentaje</th>
</tr>      


           <?php 

            foreach($consulta as $row)

            {?>

           <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row->descripcion_mot ;?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row->cantidad_motivos ;?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row->porcentaje ;?>
               </td>


           </tr>

       <?php }?>
    </table>
  <div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

El error que veo es que no estas pasando los argumentos al metodo tabla_porcentaje.

De hecho por alguna razon lo estas invocando dos veces una vez correctamente y una incorrecta.

Sin embargo la invocacion encorrecta es la que asignas a $data['consulta']
tu codigo:

```
 function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('M_Login');
    $this->load->model('M_Porcentaje');

}

 public function tabla_porcentaje(){

        $fecha_ini = $this->input->post('fecha_ini');
        $fecha_ter = $this->input->post('fecha_ter');

        $this->M_Porcentaje->tabla_porcentaje($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter);

        $data['consulta'] = $this->M_Porcentaje->tabla_porcentaje();
        $this->load->view('usuarios/test.php',$data);



 }
```

Solucion:

```
function __construct(){

parent::__construct();

$this->load->model('M_Login');
$this->load->model('M_Porcentaje');

}

 public function tabla_porcentaje(){

    $fecha_ini = $this->input->post('fecha_ini');
    $fecha_ter = $this->input->post('fecha_ter');



    $data['consulta'] = $this->M_Porcentaje->tabla_porcentaje($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter);
    $this->load->view('usuarios/test.php',$data);



 }
```

El error que mencionas que te enviá cuando haces esta corrección es por que `$data['consulta']` no es un `array` ya que solo lo retornas cuando hay resultados.

```
public function tabla_porcentaje ($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter){

$start ="$fecha_ini 08:30:00 ";
$end = "$fecha_ter 22:30:00 ";

$this->db->select('motivos_citas.descripcion_mot,COUNT(*) AS cantidad_motivos, (SELECT COUNT(motivos_citas.descripcion_mot)* 100 / COUNT(citas.id_ci) FROM citas AS citas WHERE citas.fecha_ini BETWEEN "$start" AND "$end" ) AS porcentaje');
$this->db->from('citas');
$this->db->join('motivos_citas','citas.id_mot=motivos_citas.id_mot');
$this->db->where('citas.fecha_ini BETWEEN "$start" AND "$end" ');
$this->db->group_by('motivos_citas.descripcion_mot');
$consulta = $this->db->get();

 return $consulta->result(); // Si no mal recuerdo si no hay resultados retorna un array vacio
}
```

Respecto al problema que no obtienes resultados es por que `'citas.fecha_ini BETWEEN "$start" AND "$end" '` es literalmente '`citas.fecha_ini BETWEEN "$start" AND "$end" '`.

En PHP las variables solo se puedes imprimir entre comillas dobles **"**  si lo haces entre comillas simples **'** la variable no retorna el valor.

Ejemplo:

```
$a = 'Hola';
echo "$a" //imprimirá: Hola;

$a = 'Hola';
echo '$a' //imprimirá: $a
```

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior tu debes cambiar `'citas.fecha_ini BETWEEN "$start" AND "$end" '` por `"citas.fecha_ini BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' "`

Ademas otro problema son las horas y minutos ya que pueden estar afectando los resultados de la consulta.

puedes usar la función `date()` de mysql para solo tomar en cuenta la fecha y omitir el time:

`"date(citas.fecha_ini) BETWEEN date('$start') AND date('$end') "`

Comment: Gracias, ya no me arroja los errores, aunque la consulta no me muestra ningún  resultado, supongo que se debe a que a pesar de que le estoy pasando las fechas correctamente, en  $start ="$fecha_ini 08:30:00 "; y $end = "$fecha_ter 22:30:00 "; no me esta tomando los valores correctamente ya que los campos son datatime de la base de datos, deberían quedar como  ejemplo $start= 2017-10-01 08:30:00  lo mismo con $end, le estoy asignando de manera estática las horas, pero no las esta reconociendo por lo visto.

Comment: Puedes cambiar tu where así: **$this->db->where("date(citas.fecha_ini) > date($start) and date(citas.fecha_ini )< date($end) ");** de esa forma evitas la comparación de minutos y segundos. veo que usas comillas simples para enviar la variable y ese también es un problema ya que una variable entre comillas simple no toma su valor sino que es una constante. verificarlo haciendo un **'citas.fecha_ini BETWEEN "$start" AND "$end" '**

Comment: No entendí del todo tu respuesta, para este caso debería de borrar $start ="$fecha_ini 08:30:00 "; y $end = "$fecha_ter 22:30:00 "; solo usar $fecha_ini y  $fecha_ter? no entiendo porque el date, ya que ademas de una fecha es una hora. También en la primera linea del select tengo un between con las variables para sacar el count que necesito. PD: gracias por responder nuevamente.

Comment: Edite la respuesta ahí respondo tu duda

Comment: Gracias, me quedo mucho más claro :D

Comment: Extrañamente aun así no me arroja ningún resultado, probé la consulta en la base de datos y funciona correctamente

Comment: Borre  $start ="$fecha_ini 08:30:00 "; y $end = "$fecha_ter 22:30:00 "; estoy haciendo la consulta con los date('$fecha_ini') AND date('$fecha_ter') . También cambie las comillas como mencionaste